# How to handle navigation in the flutter package?

Tags: flutter

I have created a flutter package (say `weight_calculator`) and using it from the parent flutter app.

Now I want to navigate from screen A to screen B in `weight_calculator` package, but I am not able to use the Named routes as this package doesn't have a Material App.

What will be the correct approach to do that?

Currently, I am creating a new MaterialApp inside the package.

Comment: I have the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

This actually works if you use **go_route**. 
Here is an example where u have a app showing a **screen from a package**, and that **package screen** is navigating to a **screen from the main app**.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:home_page/home_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// The route configuration.
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const HomeScreen();
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'details',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const DetailsScreen();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

/// The main app.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [MyApp]
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

/// The details screen
class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [DetailsScreen]
  const DetailsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Details Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <ElevatedButton>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/'),
              child: const Text('Go back to the Home screen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and you also just need to make a local package with the HomeScreen widget.

```
 library home_page;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

/// The home screen
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [HomeScreen]
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/details'),
              child: const Text('Go to the Details screen'),
            ),
            const Text("hello"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Worked out of the box for me.
Also this can be improved by abstraction the routes, and injecting them in to the package from the main app.